# keep custom field after deliting post in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I've created some custom fields to make it easier to add specific list items to a section in wordpress then I deleted the post and the custom fields disappear.

Does anybody knows how to **keep a custom field after deleting the original post** where they where created?

Comment: I think you can't get the custom field without the post id and once a post is deleted then you just lost the post id.

Comment: Hi Sheikh, that's what I'm thinking too but maybe someone out there knows a trick hehe =P... thanks for the response

Comment: May be you can use [option](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_option) instead.

Comment: I'll look into that function... but for now if no other answer comes I'll just keep a post with the custom fields and use another option for adding specific list items to posts on my next website... again thanks for the response Sheikh =]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use an custom meta box.
In this you can specify your values so each post can access the values:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box

Comment: thanks... came across the same answer on other forums and it seems like the best option.